# How to update app for samesite secure used in an iFrame within config

Tags: c#, google-chrome, cookies

To start with: I realize there are already many questions about samesite secure. I have read through them and based off their information, updated my application. However, I must still have a setting wrong/missing somewhere as the application is still receiving the standard samesite error message.

I am using a c#/js application. It is being used in a 3rd party iFrame.

Here is what I have in my config:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customeProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="60" cookiesamesite="None">
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" samesite="None" />
```

Should I be editing the code someplace other than the config? Is there a setting in IIS that should be updated?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth checking you meet the version requirements and have covered off all the config options in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite

There's a detailed debugging guide for `SameSite` cookie issues here: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug

Specifically, I recommend expanding the warnings in the Issues tab in Chrome DevTools as that will show you exactly which cookies are affected and why.

Comment: I have tried everything except updating the Framework. I am going to try that and see if it works.